# VF ControllerExtension: Too many query rows: 50001 - How to solve

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, custom-controller

visualforce Extension:

```
public class Autocompletefields_custom1 {

    public Autocompletefields_custom1(customreport controller) {

    }
   //Variable declaration
   transient public String[] jsonDescriptionData;
   //Constructor with argument as standrad controller
    public AutoCompletefields_custom1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { }
    //Simple construcor
    public AutoCompletefields_custom1(){}
    //Method to return all nicopin for France user
       transient public String[] jsonDescriptionData6;
    //Method to return all nicopin for France user
    public List<string> getjsonDescriptionData6(){
        jsonDescriptionData6 = new List<string>();
            //List of nicopin for france
            List<Quote_line_item__c> francePinCodeList=[SELECT name from Quote_line_item__c limit 50000];
            //Set to get all nico pin as string
            Set<String> pncodeSet=new Set<String>();
             String quoteStr='"';
            //Iterate to collect set of all nico pin
            for(Quote_line_item__c cpnCod : francePinCodeList){
                if(cpnCod.name!=Null){
                if(!cpnCod.name.contains(quoteStr)){
                    pncodeSet.add(cpnCod.name);
                }//End of if
                }
            }//End of for loop
            //Iterate to collect all pin in string format
            for(String str:pncodeSet){
                jsonDescriptionData6.add('"'+str+'"');
            }
            //To sort the nicopin list
           jsonDescriptionData6.sort();
          return jsonDescriptionData6;
    //End of method
      }
       transient public String[] jsonDescriptiondata7;
    //Method to return all nicopin for France user
    public List<string> getjsonDescriptionData7(){
        jsonDescriptionData7 = new List<string>();
            //List of nicopin for france
            List<Quote_line_item__c> francePinCodeList=[SELECT Client_P_N__c from Quote_line_item__c limit 50000];
            //Set to get all nico pin as string
            Set<String> pncodeSet=new Set<String>();
             String quoteStr='"';
            //Iterate to collect set of all nico pin
            for(Quote_line_item__c cpnCod : francePinCodeList){
            if(cpnCod.Client_P_N__c!=NULL){
                if(!cpnCod.Client_P_N__c.contains(quoteStr)){
                    pncodeSet.add(cpnCod.Client_P_N__c);
                }//End of if
                }
            }//End of for loop
            //Iterate to collect all pin in string format
            for(String str:pncodeSet){
                jsonDescriptionData7.add('"'+str+'"');
            }
            //To sort the nicopin list
           jsonDescriptionData7.sort();
          return jsonDescriptionData7;
    //End of method
      }    
      transient public String[] jsonDescriptiondata8;
    //Method to return all nicopin for France user
    public List<string> getjsonDescriptionData8(){
        jsonDescriptionData8 = new List<string>();
            //List of nicopin for france
            List<Quote_line_item__c> francePinCodeList=[SELECT N_EP_DPI__c from Quote_line_item__c limit 50000];
            //Set to get all nico pin as string
            Set<String> pncodeSet=new Set<String>();
             String quoteStr='"';
            //Iterate to collect set of all nico pin
            for(Quote_line_item__c cpnCod : francePinCodeList){
            if(cpnCod.N_EP_DPI__c!=NULL){
                if(!cpnCod.N_EP_DPI__c.contains(quoteStr)){
                    pncodeSet.add(cpnCod.N_EP_DPI__c);
                }//End of if
                }
            }//End of for loop
            //Iterate to collect all pin in string format
            for(String str:pncodeSet){
                jsonDescriptionData8.add('"'+str+'"');
            }
            //To sort the nicopin list
           jsonDescriptionData8.sort();
          return jsonDescriptionData8;
    //End of method
      }    
transient public String[] jsonDescriptiondata9;
    //Method to return all nicopin for France user
    public List<string> getjsonDescriptionData9(){
        jsonDescriptionData9 = new List<string>();
            //List of nicopin for france
            List<Quote__c> francePinCodeList=[SELECT Bill_To_Country__c from Quote__c Limit 50000];
            //Set to get all nico pin as string
            Set<String> pncodeSet=new Set<String>();
             String quoteStr='"';
            //Iterate to collect set of all nico pin
            for(Quote__c cpnCod : francePinCodeList){
            if(cpnCod.Bill_To_Country__c!=NULL){
                if(!cpnCod.Bill_To_Country__c.contains(quoteStr)){
                    pncodeSet.add(cpnCod.Bill_To_Country__c);
                }//End of if
                }
            }//End of for loop
            //Iterate to collect all pin in string format
            for(String str:pncodeSet){
                jsonDescriptionData9.add('"'+str+'"');
            }
            //To sort the nicopin list
           jsonDescriptionData9.sort();
          return jsonDescriptionData9;
    //End of method
      }    
      transient public String[] jsonDescriptiondata10;
    //Method to return all nicopin for France user
    public List<string> getjsonDescriptionData10(){
        jsonDescriptionData10 = new List<string>();
            //List of nicopin for france
            List<opportunity> francePinCodeList=[SELECT name from opportunity Limit 50000];
            //Set to get all nico pin as string
            Set<String> pncodeSet=new Set<String>();
             String quoteStr='"';
            //Iterate to collect set of all nico pin
            for(opportunity cpnCod : francePinCodeList){
            if(cpnCod.name!=NULL){
                if(!cpnCod.name.contains(quoteStr)){
                    pncodeSet.add(cpnCod.name);
                }//End of if
                }
            }//End of for loop
            //Iterate to collect all pin in string format
            for(String str:pncodeSet){
                jsonDescriptionData10.add('"'+str+'"');
            }
            //To sort the nicopin list
           jsonDescriptionData10.sort();
          return jsonDescriptionData10;
    //End of method
      }    
}
```

i am getting the error like this how can i able to solve it

> ```
> Too many query rows: 50001
> ```

Comment: Check for `SOQL` queries inside `for` loops or methods which have queries being called from `for` loops

Comment: I have kept the limit as 50000.still it hits the error why

Comment: That allowed 50000 limit is for one execution Teja, so even though you have limited it here altogether it can be more than 50000 when an execution happens

Comment: If i have 5 queries are there i can separate them 5 different classes then it will calculate for one class on e soql query as transaction or (5 class, 5 soql as one transaction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query limit applies to the sum of all queries in one transaction, so the 'limit 50000' doesn't help here.

Alternatively you can check the limits before doing the query:

```
Integer rowsLeft = Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows();
francePinCodeList = [SELECT name from Quote_line_item__c limit :rowsLeft];
```

And maybe check if rowsLeft == 0 to throw an error message

Comment: If i have 5 queries are there i can separate them 5 different classes then it will calculate for one class  on e soql query as transaction or (5 class, 5 soql as one transaction)

Comment: A transaction is the complete action (e.g. user hits a button) with all code that is executed as a consequence of this action, the number of classes doesn't matter.